# ¿Para qué sirven los folders public y app en una aplicación cualquiera?

Tags: php, web, app

Siempre me he preguntado si los folders de **public** y **app** tienen algún uso implícito a la hora de orgranizar y desarrollar aplicaciones/frameworks tanto web (que es a lo que me dedico mayoritariamente)

[image: Imágenes de los folder]

Si es que hay una razón del porque de estas carpetas, quisiera saberlo, y si no lo hay, como puedo hacer de estas carpetas útiles para mejorar mi manejo de archivos dentro de mis aplicaciones web.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en algún entorno específico: framework, IDE, etc? ¿Dónde se crearon esos directorios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a mis conocimientos y realmente no te afirmo nada debido a que esto depende de las guías de las respectivas empresas en las que puedas trabajar, normalmente la carpeta `public` es usada para meter todo el contenido que uno como usuario quiera compartir. En general, dentro de esta carpeta puedes tener otras como `movies`, `music`, `pictures` o `assets`, todo depende de como lo veas a tu conveniencia pero eso es en general lo que debería de contener.

En cuanto a la carpeta `app`, este debe de contener toda la estructura de tu aplicación, web, sistema o lo que sea que estés desarrollando en el momento. Cualquier cosa que no tenga que ver directamente con tu desarrollo como lo serían las variables de entorno o cosas como esas, (recalco que todo depende del desarrollador o de la empresa) podrías o no agregar determinados folders o archivos dentro de este.

Podría también depender de los *frameworks* ya que estos tienen su propia forma de usar los folders, pero como te digo, realmente sin importar el desarrollo que hagas, el uso de folders debe de ser de forma que no tengas tantos archivos en un mismo lugar y que su nombre indique perfectamente lo que contiene.